# If the_title starts containing the same characters as the_content then

Tags: php

Right now I have a post that `the_title` and `the_content` starts with same text: "Hello world, we are Wordpress...".

The above is just an example, every post has a different text.

What I want to do is basically, check if post content starts with the same few words as the title.

Then
//do this.

else
// do this.

I guess I need to use reggex here?

I would probably need to write how much of the first characters should match?

Maybe someone had the same situation could help me out.

thanks.

Comment: Where are you doing this - on an archive page, in The Loop? Are you using any hook?

Comment: Hey Sally, inside the loop.

Comment: So do you still need an example?

Comment: No, don't bother. I figured out the other way. Thanks for your effort in order to help!

Comment: No problem. But you might want to post your solution as an answer as it might help someone else. :)

Comment: I agree, I actually discontinued this solution at all ;) nothing to post really.